# Migrating UCM Clearcase to new Server

Tags: clearcase-ucm, server-administration

As part of an infrastructure upgrade we are Upgrading our instance of UCM clearcase and moving to new servers.
We currently have an Admin PVOB and all the project PVOBS are linked to the Admin Pvob and the Vobs linked to their PVOB.
When moving to the new VOB server will this hierarchy have to be moved big bang to ensure the admin pvob is consistent or could some sort of phased migration approach be used. Does anyone have a recommended approach?
[image: Heirarchy]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to move the PVob first, stating with the Admin one.
(provided both servers are up, and the second one is accessible from the first one)

The official documentation only mentions:

> If you use UCM and are moving a PVOB and one or more component VOBs, move the PVOB first, and then move the component VOBs.

From there, you should follow "[Moving Vob](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_mvvob.htm?view=kc)".
The other approach is to use (for older ClearCase 7.x) [Multisite to move/replicate vobs/pvobs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21266219).

Comment: Thanks VonC, Yes, the official documentation wasnt over expansive on this topic. So if I move the Admin PVOB first followed by the next layer of PVOBS before the component VOB does that maintain all the hyper links? we are using this for an upgrade from 7.1.2.6 to 8.0.1 and beginning to think this may have to all be done big bang rather than phased due to the presence of the Admin Vob.

Comment: @DBeange It should, provided the new moved PVob is properly registered in the CLearCase registry. But obviously, you need to carefully test that scenario first. When I was on CC 7, I used replica, but that should not be needed in your case.

Comment: It now appears the vob servers use a common admin vob on the aix target server so hoping I can just move and then reformat and reprotect etc